# Normality Test : Z score for Skewness & Kurtosis

Tags: spss, normality-assumption, z-score

What happens when Z score for Skewness is not within the range of -1.96 to 1.96 and Kurtosis is within the range  of -1.96 to 1.96

Z-Score for Skewness  is 2.58; Kurtosis -1.26;

I should consider this data as not normally distributed right?

I did my self-study : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiedOyglLn0

Comment: It would depend on why you need to know whether it's normal and what the consequences of violation of normality are.

Comment: What was the actual skewness value?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. The reason is because I would like to run Pearson Correlation. Skewness Value is 0.497; SE=0.192 ; Kurtosis = -0.481, SE=0.381

Comment: With skewness and kurtosis that close to 0, you'll be fine with the Pearson correlation and the usual inferences from it.  See, for example, http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13428-016-0702-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider also whether a transformation might bring the variable closer to normality.  But normality is overrated.

Comment: I will try or otherwise I will just run Spearman’s test  insteade of Pearson's correlation. Thank you so much for your help. I am very sorry, I would like to clarify what do you means by normality is overrated ? The range ? -1.96 to 1.96 ?